# Android Dev in Kotlin, confused by tutorial

Tags: android, kotlin, google-codelab

Im struggling with one of the android basics in kotlin code labs.  Im a beginner who took up programming in lockdown for fun.

[This is the tutorial in question](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-fragments-navigation-component?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-3-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-fragments-navigation-component#4)

At the begining of the tutorial it says to get a nullable reference to binding named_binding, then use

> private val binding get() = _binding!!

to get a version of it we can refer to without using the ? null safety thing. All good so far.

However in step four it shows the following code:

> override fun onCreateView(   inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,   savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
> _binding = FragmentLetterListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
> val view = binding.rootreturn view}

Why do we refer to _binding to inflate the view then binding in the next line when assigning the view?

Comment: @Alex.T It makes sense in this context. It’s the same advice given in the official documentation for setting up a binding property in a Fragment. It’s used in a similar way as `requireContext()`. You are intended to use it only while the Fragment is in started state or higher, just like `requireContext()`.

Answer (score 4):

> Why do we refer to _binding to inflate the view then binding in the next line when assigning the view?

Two concepts to understand here.

1. `_binding` is considered a *[backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields)* - that is, the actual variable reference that holds a value. In this case, the variable is a *nullable* type.
2. `binding`  is a standard *property* - that is, a thing that provides access to an underlying backing field. In this case, it's using `_binding` as a backing property as a minor convenience to expose `_binding` as a non-null.

So - since `binding` just exposes `_binding` as a non-null value, `_binding` must be set first. So that's why it's assigned the value of the inflate call. Also note that `_binding` is a `var` which means it can be re-assigned while `binding` is a `val` which means it can't. So trying to use `binding` when inflating the view would not compile.

Finally, why they use `binding` to get the view is unclear. Probably just for the sake of the convenience / consistency of using `binding` as the single property to reference the class binding. Using `_binding?.root` would work fine too.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  I think im following this now.

Comment: The reason to use the `binding/_binding` pattern is explained in the tutorial link posted by the OP: to avoid littering your code with the null safety operator (question mark.) The caveat is that you need to make sure to only access `binding` in between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView`, which corresponds to the lifecycle states `CREATED` and `DESTROYED`.

Answer (score 0):

This is best practice to protect someone modify `_binding` like `_binding = null` and you got error when access to `_binding`,

You should use `binding.root` instead `_binding.root`